# setTimeout not working correctly with jQuery and load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i have a problem with my code i have 2 tables loaded into two divs like so:

```
loadTable($("#vbeTable"),'getUpdateA')
loadTable($("#vbcTable"),'getUpdateB')
```

I also have this:

```
$("#vbeTable, #vbcTable").live('mouseover mouseout', function(event) {
    if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
//        console.log('hovering over',$(this));
        $(this).attr('update',false)
    } else {
//        console.log('NOT hovering over',$(this));
        $(this).attr('update',true)
    }
})
```

and the loadTable function is like so:

```
function loadTable($table, $php, $noRefresh){
    if($table.attr('update') == 'false'){
        console.log('not updating', $table, $table.attr('update'))
        setTimeout( function () { loadTable($table, $php); }, 1000)
    }
    $table.load($php+'.php',function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            if(!$noRefresh){
                console.log('acquired table')
                setTimeout( function () { loadTable($table, $php); }, 1000)
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log('error aquiring lock on', $table.attr('id'), response, status, xhr)
        }
    });
```

}

*for some reason the setTimeout function is not waiting the right amount of time and in the console i get:

> (96) liveLoads.js:35acquired table 
>   (7711) liveLoads.js:29not updating [ `<div
>   id=​"vbcTable"
>   update=​"true">​…​</div>`​ ] false
>   (2)`<exception> <exception> <exception> <exception>`*
>   
>   orginally both vbe and vbc are empty divs.

Can enyone help me out here?

****UPDATE****

I also have this code:

```
function expand(EntID) {
    console.log('expand',EntID)
    $.ajax({
        url: "showRows.php?ID=" + EntID
    });
}
```

which when something on the table is clicked that calls this function it runs.

but then the other functions setTimeouts go into a tizzy and they get called a million times in a row without paying attention to the time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling your timeout callback function instead of passing it to the timeout.

Instead of:

```
// this will call loadTable right away and setTimeout will trigger the returned value in a sec.
setTimeout( loadTable($table, $php), 1000)
```

Do:

```
// setTimeout will trigger the anon. function in a sec
setTimeout( function () { loadTable($table, $php); }, 1000)
```

You're also calling the same function, loadTable, from within loadTable. And I'm not seeing a break in this endless loop.

Comment: hmmm that seemed to work. why is it that just `setTimeout( loadTable($table, $php), 1000)` doesnt work?

Comment: @maniator: That's it :) The first argument of `setTimeout` needs to be a function to be called at a later date. Instead, `loadTable($table, $php)` is immediately evaluated, and its *return value* is passed to `setTimeout`, which is not what you wanted.

Comment: Because loadTable($table, $php) actually calls loadTable. The result is then passed to setTimeout.

Comment: hmmm it does not seem to work. let me add the other part of the code that i have that makes it blow up

Comment: See the update to the solution. You have a recursive function that never ends.

Comment: i want to be able to recurse. its a 'live' page. but it still blows up after expand is called anywhere

Comment: i figured it out.  i added `$noRefresh = true;` to the `if($table.attr('update') == 'false')` part of loadTable which worked

Answer (score 0):

This part looks wrong:

```
if (status == "success") {
    if(!$noRefresh){
        console.log('acquired table')
        setTimeout( loadTable($table, $php), 1000)
    }
}
```

In addition to the fact that this does not pass the correct type to setTimeout (param1 must be a function, you give it the return result of the function call to loadTable) - I don't think you want it to call loadTable ANYWAY.  Instead call a function that parses the data and populates your html elements!  So:

```
if (status == "success") {
    if(!$noRefresh){
        console.log('acquired table')
        setTimeout(function () {drawMyTableWithThisData(someTable, data);}, 1000);
    }
}
```